# Java plug-in runs only for administrators in Firefox 8

Tags: firefox, java, administrator, non-admin

I had Firefox 3.6 installed on a Windows XP with the Java plugin working fine.  I then installed Firefox 8 and now the Java plug-in only works for users with admin privileges.  The Add-Ons -> Plugins section does not list the Java Runtime for limited users.  Does anyone know how to enable this for limited users?

Note: The machine in question is not able to connect to the internet (Firefox is needed for an intranet web app in case you're wondering).

**UPDATE**

This no longer appears to be a problem with Firefox 13.0+ and Java 1.6.0_30+

Comment: Same problem here. Windows XP Administrator installed Firefox 8 and confirm Java Runtime plugin enabled and tested java applet successful. The user profile is then copied to default user for all other limited users. "Other limited users" login (from domain) logged in and start his Firefox 8 for his first time, and could NOT find Java Runtime plugin available to do anything setup nor configuration. Note: Machine could be able to go internet, however default is not enabled (via proxy).

Comment: You should list the version of Java.

Comment: Has this been resolved in newer versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappears  with Firefox 13.0+ and Java 1.6.0_30+

Comment: I am still having the same problem with Java 1.6.0_19 and Firefox 20.0.1.  I am stuck using the older version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Java Plugin for users with limited user rights (Standard User), please set security on HKLM\Software\SysWoW6432Node\mozilla.org to User:FullAccess.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While your answer maybe fixes the problem, it seems to pose a security threat. The accepted answer (using versions in which the bug is fixed) should be preferred whenever possible.